# Laravel request()->ajax() triggering on browser back button

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Inside my controller I have this function for the route `/backups`

```
public function index()
{
    $backups = \App\Backup::all();

    if(request()->ajax()) {
        return $backups;
    }

    return view('backups.index', compact('backups'));
}
```

My idea was that if I have my javascript ask for the data then return `json` if not return `html`.

This works fine, except when pressing the browser back button to go from lets say `/backups/1` to `/backups` it shows the `json`.

Is there another function I can use that will only respond to ajax calls from my code and not the browsers?

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend adding an ajax-only query string parameter to the ajax request, e.g. `?ajax=1`.

This way, you can 1. utilise the browser cache, and 2. keep the same Laravel route for both request types.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your AJAX requests use a different URL from the full HTML documents. Chrome (and most probably Firefox) caches the most recent request even if it is just a partial.

**Source:**

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108425

**Or:**

Try setting cache to false

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {...}
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this go against REST conventions though?

Comment: @robertmylne probably but I have only tried the above solutions and they worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
public function index()

{
    $backups = \App\Backup::all();

    if(request()->wantsJson()) {
        return $backups;
    }

    return view('backups.index', compact('backups'));
}

//Ajax code
$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    cache: false,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (res) {},
    error: function (err) {}
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).